# テキストをオートスクロールさせたい

Tags: ios, objective-c

タイトル通りなんですが、iOSのミュージックアプリの曲タイトルなどのように自動で横スクロールさせる方法を教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

残念ながらiOSには、テキストを「自動で横スクロールさせる」ようなUI部品はないようです。

iOSのミュージックアプリでどのような方法がとられているかはわかりませんが、ご質問に書かれたようなことをやるために思いつくところを書いておきます。

(1) 「自動で」は諦めて、あなたのコードで全てコントロールする

コードでメインViewに貼り付けた子Viewの位置を変更するのは簡単ですし、UIScrollViewなんてものを使うこともできそうです。…と思ってコードを書きかけたのですが、思っていたより大変で、回答としては長すぎるのと、Swiftで書いてしまったので、掲載は控えておきます。

うまく探せばフリーのライブラリーなど見つかるかもしれません。

(2) WebViewを使ってmarquee系のタグを流し込む

UIWebViewを横に細長く貼り付けてIBOutletにしておいて、

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

それにmarquee系のタグを流し込めば、

```
        webView.loadHTMLString("<marquee>iOSのミュージックアプリの曲タイトルなどのように自動で横スクロールさせる方法を教えていただきたいです</marquee>", baseURL: nil)
```

(とりあえずSwiftで動作確認したんで、Swiftのコード例で我慢してください。)
簡単という意味ではこれが一番簡単でしょうか。`<marquee>`タグはHTML5だと非推奨だとか(iOS9.3のUIWebViewでもちゃんと横スクロールはしますが)、フォントや背景色などをいじろうと思うと流し込むHTML+CSSがやたらでかくなるとかはありますが。

(3) SKScene中にテキストスプライトを置いて流れるように移動させる

手間がかかる割にメリットが見当たらないですね。SKSceneの中だけで展開するゲームならやっているアプリもあるかもしれませんが、普通のアプリではやらないでしょう。

Comment: オートスクロールなるヘッダーを見つけたのでそれを元に試行錯誤してみます。回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 良い結果が出ましたら、ご自身の質問への回答としてでもご紹介いただければ、多くのiOS開発者の参考になると思います。ご健闘を。